# Why the last line of my dynamic TextField doesn't appears?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, textfield, htmltext

I'm trying to write various texts in various dynamics text fields, who have a variable height. When i do all my tests in AIR 3.2 for Apple, all the texts fields are ok. 
Then i started the tests using AIR 3.2 for Android, and when i'm using the AIR Debug Launch (Desktop or Mobile), all the texts fields are ok too, but when i try on Device via USB, the last line of some of text fields just don't appear.

I tested some lines:

```
txtTexto.x = offsetX;
txtTexto.y = offsetYInicial;
txtTexto.width = 700;
txtTexto.wordWrap = true;
txtTexto.multiline = true;
txtTexto.border = false;
txtTexto.setTextFormat(justityFormat);
txtTexto.mouseEnabled = false;
txtTexto.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
//txtTexto.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
//txtTexto.gridFitType = GridFitType.SUBPIXEL;
//txtTexto.scrollV = 0;
```

i'm freaking out, seriously.

Comment: Have you embedded the font you're using in the text field?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work too.

Comment: Is the last line being truncated because the text field isn't tall enough, or do you see "whitespace" instead of text?